# I built a simple iOS calculator but I can not figure out how to add a decimal point

Tags: ios, objective-c

I built a simple calculator app and am struggling to add the decimal point button,

when I push the decimal button it will add the decimal but after I enter another number the

decimal point disappears so something is for sure wrong.

If someone can specifically walk me trough how to fix the issue since I am a beginner and get the decimal to work I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int Method;
int SelectNumber;
float RunningTotal;
int currentNumber;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController


{


IBOutlet UILabel * Screen;
}



-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number3:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number4:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number5:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number6:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number7:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number8:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number9:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Number0:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Times:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Devide:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Subtract:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)PLus:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Equalls:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)AllClear:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender;



@end
```

here is the code for the decimal in the .m file

```
- (IBAction)Decimal:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSRange range = [self->Screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];
    if (range.location ==NSNotFound){
        self->Screen.text = [ self->Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
       }
```

Comment: Please only use relevant tags. This has nothing to do with C#, asp.net, or MySQL.

Comment: Also, please narrow down the posted code to the relevant code, not the entire file. Do some debugging and narrow down the issue. Don't expect others to simply review all of your code for you.

Comment: Don't add the number presses to a number. Use them to generate a string. Then when you need it to be a number (at calculation time) use a number formatter to read the strong into a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your are printing your result as integer, change it to float %f, and u can even choose how many of decimals you need: %.02f = 25.00